# How to create a very basic thread function in C

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I have a limited amount of c experience and virtually no experience using threads. If there is a simple way to wrap the "forever" function into a thread and allow main() to continue running, please let me know how it can be done. This example is totally impractical of course but if I can get it to work, I think its a good starting point. Maybe its not even possible? But would like to know. Thanks!

```
//
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

void foreverFunction(); // function prototype

int myNumber=1;

void main()
{

    foreverFunction();   // call forever (looping function), would like get it running as a separate thread so that the code below can continue.
    while (myNumber != 0 ){
        printf("Enter a number (0 to exit): ");
        scanf("%d",&myNumber);
        printf("Entered: %d\n",myNumber);
    }

}


// function below should report the current value of myNumber every second
void foreverFunction(){
while (myNumber>0){
    printf ("\nThis will run until the user enters 0, Last value entered was %d\n",myNumber);
    Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please pick *one* language.

Comment: are you using c++11?

Comment: Windows, Linux, MacOS ??

Comment: C, Windows (see headers included), VizStudio 2010.

Comment: How far can you go with [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) ? Please try and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, working with an example provided on that page and will report back if I get it working.

Comment: @Quentin Tried the second example given on that page (crt_begthrdex.cpp - as I have the option of writing this in C++ too). Intitally gives 
_"fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?"_
If I add the header - results in a series of "identifier not found" / "undeclared identifier" errors when I try to compile

Comment: @Tommy you can disable the precompiled stdafx header in your project's properties. Also, don't be afraid of editing your question. Just make sure you don't invalidate any answer when doing so (comments are OK).

Comment: @Quentin Thanks - once I went into Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers I got this to compile and I was able to adapt my program to run the function as a thread.

Answer (score 1):

for a simple program like yours you can use [beginthread()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kdzttdcb%28v=VS.120%29.aspx)

```
_beginthread(foreverfunction, 0, NULL);
```

the first argument is a function pointer (the name of your function). The second is the stack size and can be 0. The third is a parameter you want give your function (more specific, a pointer to the parameter). If you have multiple arguments you have to pack them into a struct

another function you could use in Windows is [CreateThread()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Linux (POSIX) see haris answer

Comment: Thanks. Got it working with the first answer (See comments) but I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

If you're working on linux, you can use the `pthread` for this purpose. For your example, to keep the `function` running forever, you can do something like

```
pthread_t thread1;

pthread_create (&thread1, NULL, (void *) &foreverFunction);
pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
```

Now, your function won't exit until `main` exits. This is taken care by the `pthread_join()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated code (from the example above) which is working and doing exactly what I expect. Thanks to all.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <process.h>

int myNumber=1;

// function below should report the current value of myNumber every second
unsigned __stdcall foreverFunction(void* pArguments){

printf("The thread is started...\n");

while (myNumber>0){
    printf ("Selected number: %d\n",myNumber);
    Sleep(1000);
    }
printf("The thread as exited... \n");
return NULL;
}      

void main()
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    unsigned threadID;

    hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &foreverFunction, NULL, 0, &threadID );

    while (myNumber != 0 ){
        printf("Enter a number (0 to exit): ");
        scanf("%d",&myNumber);
        printf("Entered: %d\n",myNumber);
    }

}
```

The Console Output:

```
Enter a number (0 to exit): The thread is started...
Selected number: 1
Selected number: 1
Selected number: 1
Selected number: 1
Selected number: 1
3
Entered: 3
Enter a number (0 to exit): Selected number: 3
Selected number: 3
Selected number: 3
Selected number: 3
Selected number: 3
Selected number: 3
Selected number: 3
54
Entered: 54
Enter a number (0 to exit): Selected number: 54
Selected number: 54
Selected number: 54
Selected number: 54
```